# SVG circular progress bar - display score at the end of the progress bar

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, svg, progress-bar

I'm building a circular progress bar as a react component with SVG elements.

Desired output:

[image]

Instead, I get it like this

[image]

My question is, how to rotate the score/text in the yellow circle to match the first image?

React component

```html
const Gauge = ({ width, height, thick, progress, score }) => {

    let angle = (progress / 100 * 360);
    let progressValue = angle / 2;

    let ticks = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= 180; i++) {
        let tickClass = (progressValue > i) ? styles.tickActive : styles.tick;
        ticks.push(<use key={i} className={tickClass} href="#tick" transform={`rotate(${i * 2} 60 60)`}> </use>)
    }

    ticks.push(<use key={0} className={styles.tickActive } href="#tick" transform={`rotate(0 60 60)`}> </use>);


    return (

        <div className={ styles.svgContainer }>

            <svg className={styles.progress} width={`${width}`} height={`${height}`} viewBox="-20 -20 160 160">

                <defs>
                    <line id="tick" x1="-5" y1="60" x2={`${thick}`} y2="60"> </line>
                </defs>

                <g id="ticks">
                    {ticks}
                </g>

                <g transform={`rotate(${progressValue * 2} 60 60)`}>
                    <line className={styles.scoreCircle} x1="0" y1="60" x2="0" y2="60"> </line>
                    <text className={styles.score2} fontSize={8} x={-10} y={63}>
                        {score}K
                    </text>
                </g>

            </svg >

        </div>

    );
          

};
```

Comment: if you rotate the group 30 degs `<g transform="rotate(30 60 60)">` you may try to rotate the text -30 degs `<text x=-10 y=63 transform="rotate(-180 -10 63)">`

Comment: You were close. I added this, then it worked     let rotateReverse = ( ( progressValue * 2 ) * -1) -90 ; <text className={styles.score2} fontSize={8} x="-10" y="63" transform={`rotate(${ rotateReverse } 0 60)`}>